# Filter a dictionary from a list of keys

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, generator

I want to filter a dictionary based on a set/list/(dict) of keys.

Currently I'm using a generator like this:

```
def filter_dict(in_dict, in_iterator):
    for key, value in in_dict.items():
        if key in in_iterator:
            yield key, value


d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
l = ['one', 'two']

for key, value in filter_dict(d, l):
    print(key, value)
```

Which works great and filters correctly with the result:

```
one 1
two 2
```

Is there a better or more standardized way to do this?

Maybe something like `filter(d, l)` or `d.items(l)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through all the keys and then checking if it is present in another list, you could simply walk through the list and pick items from the dict and create a new dict.

```
new_dict = dict( ((key, d[key]) for key in l) )
```

Comment: yeah, you are right. The generator in this case should go through the list and return the dict items if they exists.

Comment: Or just use a dictionary comprehension: `{k: d[k] for k in l}`. This avoids the generator expression / explicit construction of tuples.

Comment: which then becomes in the example above `for key, value in {k: d[k] for k in l}.items()`
Both examples gives an error if `l` contains a key that does not exists `d`

Answer (score 2):

if items of your list not in your dictionaries you get error if you use this: 
it takes about 5 seconds to complete it

```
new_dict = dict(((key, d[key]) for key in l))
```

you can use something like this:

and you can be sure you won't get the error if items of your list not in your dictionaries

```
keys = set(l).intersection(d)
result = {key:d[key] for key in keys}
```

but it takes about 17 seconds, and it doesn't good performance 

you can use this and it takes about 5 seconds to complete it and you can be sure you won't get any error:

```
result = {}
for k in set(d1).intersection(l1):
    result[k]= d1[k]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and time comparison.
Are your suggestion the following according to the question?
`for key in set(d).intersection(l):`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to perform set operation on `dict.keys()`:

```
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
l = ['one', 'two']

for k in d.keys() & set(l):
    print(k, d[k])
```

Prints:

```
one 1
two 2
```

Comment: great! And a nice solution. But maybe we lose a bit of readability?